# how to play webRTc audio stream?

Tags: ios, swift, streaming, webrtc

I have created my peer connection between two iOS devices. Through which I'm receiving audio stream. [A=1:V=0]
I'm in a question that how would I play this audio stream? does webRTC handles it? DO i need some player for this?

Answer (score 2):

You don't say how you are using WebRTC as there are quite a few examples and frameworks, but the simple answer is that no you should not have to create anything to actually play the audio yourself.

One check is to make sure you have audio enabled:

> RTCAudioSession.sharedInstance().isAudioEnabled = true

Assuming audio is enabled then you might be best to look at some of the existing iOS webRTC material as a starting point and either use them in your project or use them to compare with your code - e.g.:

- https://github.com/stasel/WebRTC-iOS
- https://webrtc.org/native-code/ios/

Comment: Hello, I am currently working with webrtc, after I have received the remote stream I see [Add stream Remote: RTCMediaStream:defaultA=1V=1] but it doesn't work for me when i show up, do you have any solution for me, thank you very much.

Comment: @HiềnĐỗ - I think you would be best to open a new question for this

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I was banned from asking questions, and now I can only ask cmt for help.